# Get all possible values ​of a M2M field in a model

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have three models :

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    city = models.ManyToManyField(City)
```

In my database, there is 120 cities and 25 countries. 
But the restaurants created are located in 20 cities only.

Problem : 
I need a query to retrieve all the cities where my restaurants are located. And another query to retrieve all the countries where my restaurants are located.

**Solution :**

For the first query, i used the idea proposed by @Daniel Roseman :

```
City.objects.exclude(restaurant=None)
```

For the second query, I kept getting empty queryset. I had to user filter :

```
Country.objects.exclude(city__restaurant__isnull=False).distinct()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just follow the relationships.

```
City.objects.exclude(restaurant=None)
```

and

```
Country.objects.exclude(city__restaurant=None)
```

Comment: This will got through all the instances. Is using something like this more efficient ? 
`[city for city in City.objects.all() if Restaurant.objects.filter(city=city).exists()]`

Comment: I did the test. Your query is faster.

Comment: After verification, the second query is not working. It returns empty queryset.